# How can I "require" two things in one rule of kframework?

Tags: kframework

I want to "require" two things in one rule. I wrote something like

```
rule left => right
  requires notBool(X in keys(A))
  requires notBool(L in keys(B))
```

But it does not work. Is there a way in K to set multiple constraints on one rule?

Answer (score 3):

You need to separate boolean conditions with the boolean and operator, which we write as  `andBool`. The following should work:

```
rule left => right
  requires notBool(X in keys(A))
   andBool notBool(L in keys(B))
```